# In Snowflake, how to correctly grant read access to a role on database created and edited by another role?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I’ve setup the user and role access as shown below. I only included the SYSADMIN tree, as the rest is default.

[image]

**Problem description:** I’m trying to set it up such that DEV_ROLE can write new data into DEV, and TABLEAU_ROLE should be able to READ data from DEV. Problem is when I create a new table in DEV (eg. DEV.LUDWIG.DELIVERY_STOCK_ITEM). This table is not visible from the TABLEAU_ROLE.

**My role setup.**

- I created my warehouses and databases using SYSADMIN
- I created my role using SECURITYADMIN, and granted access using SECURITYADMIN
- Privileges granted to TABLEAU_ROLE are as shown below:

  GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

  GRANT USAGE ON ALL SCHEMAS IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

  GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE SCHEMAS IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

  GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

  GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE TABLES IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

I am quite confused why TABLEAU_ROLE is not seeing the table created by DEV_ROLE in DEV, even though TABLEU_ROLE has been granted access to all current and future tables within DEV.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry guys. I found out the problem!

Turns out the "Table" I created wasn't a "table", but was a "view", and I never granted any privileges to the "view"

Added the following two lines and everything is working now.

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL VIEWS IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;

GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE VIEWS IN DATABASE DEV TO ROLE TABLEAU_ROLE;
```